# SAS Macro Statement %If and %Let

Tags: if-statement, sas-macro

I am trying to solve a problem in which, based on certain conditions, it assigns you a parameter with the let function. For this exercise I am using %if with %let conditions on the code. The code I have written so far in simplified way is the following:

```
%let anio = 2022;
%let base = 2;

%Macro Data;
%if &anio = 2022 %then %do;
%Let year_add = %Str(&Base.C);
%Let year_add1 = %Str(&Base.B);
%mend;

%Data;

%put &=year_add;
%put &=year_add1;
```

The problem is that apparently the macro is not assigning any value to me in the second let statement

The first %put = &year_add gives me the correct result 2C.

Unfortunately with the second %put = &year_add1 it appears the following message: apparent symbolic referenc yeard_add1 not resolved

Can anyone can give me a hand or advise on how I can assign different let statements based on a condition?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Completely unrelated to Tom's answer: check if your %put statement showing you your result is correct. Because in your error message you have a macro variable yeard_add1 and not year_add1.

Answer (score 1):

Your macro definition is missing an %END for the %DO.

```
%macro data;
%if &anio = 2022 %then %do;
%let year_add = &Base.C;
%let year_add1 = &Base.B;
%end;
%mend;
```

If the target macro variables, YEAR_ADD and YEAR_ADD1 do not already exist then your macro will create them as LOCAL to the DATA macro. So once the macro finishes they will be removed.

The easiest solution is just to make sure the macro variables exist before you call the macro.

```
%let anio = 2022;
%let base = 2;
%let year_add=;
%let year_add1=;

%data;

%put &=year_add;
%put &=year_add1;
```

If you are certain the macro variables do not already exist in some other macro that is calling %DATA() then you could add a %GLOBAL statement to define them in the GLOBAL macro scope so they will not be removed when the macro finishes by adding this to the macro definition:

```
%global year_add year_add1 ;
```

But that will generate an error if they have been defined as LOCAL to some other macro that called %DATA.  So to be safe only force them into the GLOBAL scope if they do not already exist.

```
 %if not %symexist(year_add) %then %global year_add;
 %if not %symexist(year_add1) %then %global year_add1;
```

But the logic does not require you to define a macro.  Just use the %IF/%THEN/%DO/%END block in open code. Then you won't have any macro variable scoping issues.

```
%if &anio = 2022 %then %do;
%let year_add = &Base.C;
%let year_add1 = &Base.B;
%end;
```

That works fine unless you are running on some really old version of SAS.